# "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Send requests' and limit 'Send requests per minute' of service 'fcm.googleapis.com'

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

1"I send messages to 1000 user tokens every 100 milliseconds using the below code
`BatchResponse resp = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app).sendMulticast(message, dryRun);`.

However, I encountered an error:
"errorCode": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
"message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Send requests' and limit 'Send requests per minute' of service 'fcm.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:687676053922'.",
"localizedMessage": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Send requests' and limit 'Send requests per minute' of service 'fcm.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:687676053922'.",
"suppressed": []

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2n9e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w38ns.png)

2 'Send requests per minute' means what? Is it the number of API calls per minute or the number of tokens sent per minute?

3 "Also, is there any connection between 'google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmService.SendMessage' and 'BatchResponse resp = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app).sendMulticast(message, dryRun)'?"

I've already checked the Firebase documentation and couldn't find the meaning of 'Send requests per minute.' I'm trying to understand why my sending logic is hitting the limit of 'Send requests per minute.